# Is map(sum,zip(*list)) the fastest way to sum columns of list of arbitrary length?

Tags: python, performance, list, optimization

I would like to know if anyone can suggest a way to sum lists that is faster than map(sum, zip(*list)).

Example:

```
import timeit

print timeit.Timer('''
[ (a[x]+b[x]+c[x]) for x in xrange(len(a)) ]
''', '''
a = range(200)
b = range(199,-1,-1)
c = range(1,201)
''').timeit(number = 1000)

print timeit.Timer('''
map(sum,zip(*d))
''', '''
a = range(200)
b = range(199,-1,-1)
c = range(1,201)
d = [a,b,c]''').timeit(number = 1000)

print timeit.Timer('''
[sum(x) for x in zip(*d)]
''', '''
a = range(200)
b = range(199,-1,-1)
c = range(1,201)
d = [a,b,c]''').timeit(number = 1000)
```

Results:

```
0.0317891459248 #list comprehension
0.0406545608382 #sum with zip
0.0532605665307 #map sum with zip
```

**Note: I know I am nitpicking, but I'm just curious if anyone has a better suggestion.**

Comment: `itertools.izip` may be more efficient

Comment: @Hooked -- Really?  I'm not sure that I believe that ... The parenthesis don't do anything and should be removed by the parser.

Comment: @mgilson I think you are correct - I tried a timing test and it showed that % change and it was reproducible - until it wasn't. I've removed the comment. For posterity, the comment deleted claimed that the first example was faster if the `()` were removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this one?

```
print timeit.Timer('''
d.sum(axis=0)
''', '''
import numpy as np
a = range(200)
b = range(199,-1,-1)
c = range(1,201)
d = np.array([a,b,c])''').timeit(number = 1000)
```

Of course, this assumes that your lists contain some sort of numeric type...

Comment: It seems faster, but if you count the time spent transforming the list into a numpy array, it's substantially slower - so I suppose there's a caveat here.

Comment: @Tim_Y now if your data `a,b,c` was _already_ a numpy array, that's a totally different story...

Comment: @Hooked - yes, that's what I meant in my comment.

Comment: @Tim_Y -- Yeah.  I think the point is that if you want efficiency with numeric arrays, then selecting numpy ndarrays as your datatype is a good design decision.  The code will be easier to read and execute faster than the alternative.

Comment: @mgilson To match with OP's examples, that needs to be `axis=0`, otherwise you end up with simply returning the sum of `a,b,c` not the sum along each column.

Comment: @Hooked -- You're right.  It's still (not surprisingly) faster (I checked just in case).  My answer is updated.  Thanks.